# Insert datetime from C# into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

when I try to insert `datetime` value into a SQL Server database I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Code:

```
connection.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into table values(@time)", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", DateTime.Now);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Table `table` has 1 `datetime` column called `time`.

Edit:
my table created in msSQL 2012: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaxag.png
my real code is:

```
public void vytvorDotaz(String uzivatel, DateTime cas, String nazev, String dotaz)
    {
        int id = getMaxID() + 1;
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into otazky values('" + id + "', '" + uzivatel + "', '0','0','0','@cas','" + nazev + "','" + dotaz + "')", connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cas", DateTime.Now);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Does your insert statement really have **one** single quote or is that a mistype?

Comment: Side note: as of SQL Server **2008**, there's a new datatype called `TIME` - it's really bad idea to call a column just `time` - use something more meaningful, more expressive!

Comment: Please write out the actual SQL instead of a dummy-sql for the question. Also, what is the type of the column you're trying to store a DateTime into?

Comment: And this is your *actual* code? Not just the code how you understand it? I ask because there is no way you're going to get a conversion error with that code. `AddWithValue` will add a DateTime value, not a string value.

Comment: Next time don't dumb down the code in your question unless you can reproduce the problem *with* that code, save yourself and everyone else some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem here is that you're writing the parameter inside quotes:

```
... ,'0','@cas',' ...
         ^    ^
```

This will not use @cas as a parameter, you're actually trying to insert the string "@cas" into that column, not the contents of the parameter @cas.

Remove the quotes and that part should work.

Additionally, don't use string concatenation to build up the SQL, use parameters for everything, save you some headache from SQL injection attacks or quotes or whatnot. This is related to the "id", "uzivatel", "nazev", and "dotav" parameters you're using (method parameters that is).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need:

```
 insert into table values(@time)
```

Without the single character quote.

Comment: ah I am so sorry, this mistake was made by me when I was clearing code (normally I have more than 1 parameter)...My problem is with that converting asp datetime into SQL datetime....I edited code, but thnx

Answer (score 0):

Try [System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1ys9ehh.aspx) Also when storing dates please consider storing them as UTC to prevent confusion.

Comment: I missed the single quote as mentioned by @Darren, that is more likely to be the issue.